# Open image viewer from url stored in data bases android

Tags: android, image, image-viewer

I am working on android application in which i am storing image in data bases, and on displaying time my url is like : `http://files.parsetfss.com/ee6c904a-c395-4a92-bb80-9fe687901411/tfss-4a6bdb3c-5818-4057-964f-99bcf23f3d35-1425711426766.jpg` I have seen codes to open image viewer by using File name like the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
           intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"image/png");
           mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

But the problem is that my url is not in file format, at the time of image displaying i am using the following code:

```
 String url "";
    url = data.getText(); // Coming from the data base as a link
    Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(url).into(mHolder.mImgReceived);
```

I need to open image viewer from that link which is coming from databases `http://files.parsetfss.com/ee6c904a-c395-4a92-bb80-9fe687901411/tfss-4a6bdb3c-5818-4057-964f-99bcf23f3d35-1425711426766.jpg` . At the time of displaying it with picasso it is showing me the picture, i need to open the same image with image viewer. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
String url "";
    url = data.getText(); // Coming from the data base as a link

     Uri myUri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(myUri , "image/png");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code snippet

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + a), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);

            //a is path to image
            a = "/storage/primery/lagacy/kids/123.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this method

```
 public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}


public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}



public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}


public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```